# WHy does my triangle refuse to rotate?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-11

I have a triangle created in DirectX11. I now want to play around with viewport and world matrices to help my understanding of them, so Id like to simply rotate the triangle around the Z axis. My code for attempting to do that is below.

```
void Render(void)
{
    if (d3dContext_ == 0)
        return;

    XMMATRIX view = XMMatrixIdentity();
    XMMATRIX projection = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f); .
    XMMATRIX vpMatrix_ = XMMatrixMultiply(view, projection);

    XMMATRIX translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XMMATRIX rotationZ = XMMatrixRotationZ(30.0f);
    XMMATRIX TriangleWorld = translation * rotationZ;

    XMMATRIX mvp = TriangleWorld*vpMatrix_;
    mvp = XMMatrixTranspose(mvp);

    float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f };
    d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);
    unsigned int stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
    unsigned int offset = 0;


    d3dContext_->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout_); 
    d3dContext_->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer_, &stride, &offset); 
    d3dContext_->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST); 
    d3dContext_->VSSetShader(solidColorVS_, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->PSSetShader(solidColorPS_, 0, 0);

    d3dContext_->UpdateSubresource(mvpCB_, 0, 0, &mvp, 0, 0);
    d3dContext_->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &mvpCB_); 

    d3dContext_->Draw(3, 0); 
    swapChain_->Present(0, 0);
}
```

It just displays the standard triangle, its as if it does not take notice of the mvp. 
My desired effect is the rotation as controlled  by `XMMATRIX rotationZ = XMMatrixRotationZ(30);`.

Thanks

Comment: Please, edit your question to show us HLSL part, specifically `solidColorVS_` implementation.

Comment: Hi, I found out that there indeed lied my problem in the HLSL part. It just kept with the unchanged vertex's positions. I am fixing it up now and will post an ans once I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`XMMatrixRotationZ` takes a radian as parameter, not degrees (see [MSDN Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixrotationz%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ).
To get degrees from radians, you have to multiply by `M_PI / 180.0f`

```
XMMATRIX rotationZ = XMMatrixRotationZ(30 * M_PI / 180.0);
```

Comment: Hi, yes I had thought that may have been a problem. But any value I put in be it 0.2, 2 or 20 does not change the triangle's orientation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know from OpenGl you must increase the XMMatrixRotationZ-value for an animated rotation a little bit per tick, because otherwise you only draw it once in the specific angle.

So (if you haven't) create a loop for your render function and increase the angle-value per round

Hope i could help

Comment: Hi, I am actually just after an image of a static rotated triangle to start with. I have a timer implemented for the gradual increase later on, but even with it set as a static value of '30', I am expecting the triangle to be on a different angle. Thanks

Comment: hmmm have you tested it also for X & Y axis?
also use the grad to radient-calculation from user1781290

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried them. I have also tried changing the XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) values and it doesn't budge an inch.

Comment: EDIT: can you work with the function on your mpv matrix? like:
`mpv = mpv.XMMatrixRotationZ(...);`
I think your problem is, you don't apply the rotation to your mpv matrix...

Comment: EDIT: should use my glasses ^^" sry you do alreay.
please try change `XMMATRIX TriangleWorld = translation * rotationZ;` to `XMMATRIX TriangleWorld = rotationZ * translation;`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. My triangle is constructed of VertexPos gVertices[] = 
{
 XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), 
 XMFLOAT3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
 XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f)
};, and then fed into the vertex buffer. I have tried changing the order to no avail. But something should change if I have values in both the translation and rotation matrix even if the orders are out of whack. So there is definitely something not getting applied.

Comment: have you tried switching rotation and translation? because a similar problem is faced [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/624371-rotating-a-sprite-around-its-center-directx11/)

Comment: i think that it is applyed, but in the wrong order. Look [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=7ZkLAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA251&ots=xulVllk5u7&dq=xmmatrix%20rotation&hl=de&pg=PA252#v=onepage&q=xmmatrix%20rotation&f=false) some good examples and explanations
it could be at the triangel/vpmartix mutiply

Comment: I have tried the different orders. The main problem is that even if I change the arguments of XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), there is no movement. I think there is a problem with a globally defined variable that is not updating as it should, but just cannot figure it out...

Comment: Have you tried to set the mvp to totally wrong numbers, just to see if it is used at all? Your projection matrix looks suspiciously different than your vertex coordinates?

Comment: Hi, I am manipulation some code from a tutorial. I think you are right my mvp is not being used at all. When I add in translation with crazy numbers nothing changes. The frustrating thing is when the book used sprites, this code worked. The difference was the sprites were added in via XMMATRIX world = sprites_[i].GetWorldMatrix( ); where XMFLOAT2 sprite1Pos( 100.0f, 300.0f ); sprites_[0].SetPosition( sprite1Pos );. I am doing nothing like that in my version though. I don't want to use sprites, just the triangle from the vertices I defined.

Comment: I'm not an expert with DX, but if you are using a self-defined shader, could it be, that it simply ignores the matrix?